# Issues running Selenium to download zip file

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, url, selenium-webdriver, download

I'm trying to write a short python script to visit a web page and simulate the user clicking a download button to download a zip file. The url of this zip file changes frequently, hence the need to simulate clicking the button.

I've noticed when my script reaches the line:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

it produces the screen below:

[Output of early script attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W95He.png)

[image]

Any lines of code below this line are not reached. I am trying to call the script from within an existing batch file. Running the command above directly in a python window works correctly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show code before `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: I should add that I've also tried running a script with literally just the line of code above and I get the same result shown in the image.

Comment: How you run your script? Give some more details as it's not clear how module importing could cause result from screenshot. Maybe you've attached wrong screenshot?

Comment: Apologies - I've tried running it from a batch file. Running the command above directly in a python window works correctly.